# Manifest does not see activity - Android

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

For some reason my project have been broken. And it does not launch. It does not see the launcher activity.

Error:
[image]

But it is there
[image]

IDE is not able to recognize it as well
[image]

[image]

Comment: I keep receiving this often when importing older projects. I remember it got fixed it after doing  Invalidate Cashes / Restart.

Comment: @Rajasekhar invalidate / restart does not help me... is there other way? why it is in old projects?

Comment: I tried checking other posts and answer around, and all answers were about restarting, rebuilding project, clean build, sync, rename that activity or move to different package and try again.

Comment: @Rajasekhar fixed it with other solution

Comment: May I know what the solution was, might be useful later for others. Or update here as your answer.

Comment: @Rajasekhar added the andswer)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is inside android studio set "Launch" to "Default Activity"

[image]

[image]